# Calling function in Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have defined an object with 2 properties and a function named fullname. When I call the function fullname, I see an additional line of display being displayed.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function person(firstname,lastname){
                this.firstname = firstname;
                this.lastname = lastname;
                var id = 1;
                this.fullname = function(){
                console.log("firstname = " + firstname + " lastname = " + lastname);    
                }
            }

            x = new person("Bob","McDonald");
            console.log(x.firstname);
            console.log(x.fullname());
            console.log("Display finish");

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is the body
    </body>
</html>
```

Output from firebug-

> Bob
>   basics.html (line 14) firstname = Bob lastname = McDonald
>   basics.html (line 9) undefined
>   basics.html (line 15) Display finish

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What *is* your output? What *should* it be? What does "see an additional line of display being displayed" mean?

Comment: The function `fullname` returns `undefined`. `console.log(x.fullname())` logs that returned value.

Comment: So the console prints 4 lines, and you have 4 calls to `console.log`. What's strange about that?

Answer (score 1):

Your function `fullname` is already logging to console and returns nothing. You simply need to call it.

```
console.log(x.firstname);
x.fullname(); //no console.log
console.log("Display finish");
```

Comment: Yes, thats the problem..thanks